# Cannot complete hackerrank problem due to error in code

Tags: python

I am trying to complete a hackerrank problem in python but I cannot seem to pass it even though my output matches the correct answer. The reason I cannot pass it is due to a problem relating to the problem itself.

I have tried converting the result to a string but that didn't help. I am not sure how to fix this, and no one had this problem in the discussion forum for hackerrank. The problem line is  `fptr.write(result+'/n')`.

The code is as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    x1V1X2V2 = input().split()

    x1 = int(x1V1X2V2[0])

    v1 = int(x1V1X2V2[1])

    x2 = int(x1V1X2V2[2])

    v2 = int(x1V1X2V2[3])

    result = kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2)
#this is the problem code. I am not sure how to fix this
    fptr.write(result+"/n")

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Please include your `kangaroo` function as well as the full error.

Comment: What is the value of `result`, and how do you know that it is correct?

Comment: Did you mean to add a line break (`"\n"`) rather than `"/n"`? By the way, you could do `kangaroo(*map(int, x1V1X2V2))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted my code successfully, the following code should work. Just change "/n" to '\n'. Note that your kangaroo function should return "YES" or "NO".

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    x1V1X2V2 = input().split()

    x1 = int(x1V1X2V2[0])

    v1 = int(x1V1X2V2[1])

    x2 = int(x1V1X2V2[2])

    v2 = int(x1V1X2V2[3])

    result = kangaroo(x1, v1, x2, v2)

    fptr.write(result + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Thanks man. However, I realized that the person who created the problem didn't explain the output well. Even though it says you have to print the output 5 different times, you have to return it in order to pas the test cases.

Comment: usually what I do is  I browse through the postprocessing steps to know what types of outputs are expected.